# Docker tomcat image cant able to access remote mysql server

Tags: mysql, docker, tomcat, dockerfile

Can you please help how to connect docker tomcat image with remote mysql server.

Tomcat image created by using below docker command

> docker run -d -p 7000:8080 --name tomcat tomcat:8

MySQL server is installed in remote server and tried to connect via tomcat image,But the connection gets failed

Comment: It's exactly the same as without Docker.  What specific issues are you encountering?  Can you share some code and/or configuration?

Comment: Mysql is not in docker image. I am trying connect that mysql server via tomcat docker image.